# How to fetch an object with find while also including another object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have to fetch an object like this

```
var fetchedObject = ds.Products.Find(id);
```

But I also need to add a Include() because Products contains a Supplier object. The code I was given was like

```
var fetchedObject = ds.Products.Include(“Supplier”).SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
```

How would I combine the two so I Find(id) while also Include("Supplier")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what your question is? Your second line of code there is "finding" the object with that id and also including the supplier. I think you might be misunderstanding what Include does. Include means that it will only make one round trip to the database and will retrieve the navigation property "Supplier" along with it so that this can be queried in the next line by doing something :

```
var supplier = fetchedObject.Supplier;
```

or whatever you want to do with it. Have you tried running your second line?

If you didn't write the include clause in there then the Supplier of fetched object would be lazily evaluated. That would mean that it would have to make another trip to the database if you ever decided to use Supplier.

Comment: So my question is I want to Find(id) as well as Include(Supplier). Are you saying the 2nd line of code (which was provided for me) does both things?

Comment: Yes from your description of what you want it to do I think the second line does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `Find` does some optimizations that conflict with things like `Include`. Namely, find will always return the object from the local store without issuing a query if it already has been pulled from the database.